# Running m-files from Python

Tags: python, matlab

pymat doesnt seem to work with current versions of matlab, so I was wondering if there is another equivalent out there (I havent been able to find one). The gist of what would be desirable is running an m-file from python (2.6). (and alternatives such as scipy dont fit since I dont think they can run everything from the m-file).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you do this:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> h = win32com.client.Dispatch('matlab.application')
```

Answer (score 2):

There's [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/).  Have you looked at this?  I used this several years ago, but not recently.

Answer (score 2):

You can always start matlab as separate subprocess and collect results via std.out/files. (see subprocess package).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most comprehensive Python packages to call MATLAB functions are:

- [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/)
- [matlab_wrapper](https://github.com/mrkrd/matlab_wrapper) (pure Python, no need to compile anything)

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of matlab_wrapper.