# How to solve "TypeError" and "ValueError" after calling Matlab .m files in Python3.x?

Tags: python, matlab

I want to call Matlab .m-files and functions in Python, but because of different data type between Matlab and Python, an error occurs about `TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray`.

As an example in the below code, `VoxelSizeUnification` is a Matlab function that I want to call it in Python and its inputs are from Python data types:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

xyzSpacing = [dcm_image.SliceThickness, dcm_image.PixelSpacing[1], dcm_image.PixelSpacing[0]]
xyzNewSpacing = [1.25, 1.25, 1.25]
eng.VoxelSizeUnification(volume_image, xyzNewSpacing, xyzSpacing)  # TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray
```

that:

```
volume_image is {ndarray} and includes images as: volume_image[number of slices in 3rd dimenson = 133, rows=512, columns=512].
xyzNewSpacing and xyzSpacing are <class 'list'> with size of (1 x 3)
```

Also, I searched using [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997254/converting-numpy-arrays-to-matlab-and-vice-versa), but I don't want to save files and then load them. Also in [link2](https://github.com/ewiger/mlab), mlab should work with python>=2.7 and my Python is 3.6.6 and Matlab 2017b.

Also, I have tried by `matlab.double` and tested above code with an example, **without any error**:

```
xyzNewSpacing = matlab.double([1.25, 1.25, 1.25])
xyzSpacing = matlab.double([1.5, 1.5, 1.5])
vol = matlab.double([[[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 5], [2, 1, 2]],
                     [[2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]],
                     [[4, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1]]])
ret = eng.VoxelSizeUnification(vol, xyzNewSpacing, xyzSpacing)
```

But for `volume_image` that is a 3D array of images, I receive an error about: `ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence`.

Python:

```
xyzNewSpacing = matlab.double([1.25, 1.25, 1.25])
xyzSpacing = matlab.double([1.5, 1.5, 1.5])
d = matlab.double(volume_image) # ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence
ret = eng.VoxelSizeUnification(d, xyzSpacing, xyzNewSpacing)
```

Matlab:

```
function outputSize = VoxelSizeUnification(d, xyzSpacing, xyzNewSpacing)
         outputSize = [ceil((d(1)*xyzSpacing(1))/xyzNewSpacing(1))...
                      ceil((d(2)*xyzSpacing(2))/xyzNewSpacing(2))...
                       ceil((d(3)*xyzSpacing(3))/xyzNewSpacing(3))];
end
```

What is the reason of `ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence`? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [`matlab.double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html) as the second answer in your first link described?

Comment: @excaza: Yes, but because of `volume_image` that is a 3D array, I receive an error about: `ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence`.  For example, If we have `xyzNewSpacing = matlab.double([1.25, 1.25, 1.25])`, `xyzSpacing = matlab.double([1.5, 1.5, 1.5])` , `d = matlab.double(volume_image)` , `ret = eng.triarea(d, xyzSpacing, xyzNewSpacing)` and `ret = np.array(ret)`, that error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was because of `datatypes` and using `volume_image = volume_image.tolist()` the error was solved. However, it was taken a lot of running time. So, if everyone has a good idea please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using mlabwrap?

Check this link out- might be of some help

[Calling MATLAB .m-files and functions in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457751/calling-matlab-m-files-and-functions-in-python-script)

Comment: Yes, I search for an equivalent datatype between Python and Matlab. I have checked [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html) and I have used `list` or `tuple` but they couldn't be solved the error.  Also [mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457751/calling-matlab-m-files-and-functions-in-python-script) should work with python>=2.7 and my Python is 3.6.6.